# Component in Vue.js server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, vue-router, server-side-rendering, vue.js

I am trying to make my Vue app have server-side rendering. I am using `vue-server-renderer` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-server-renderer). Client-side rendering is working fine.

My app use `vue-router` and `axios`

Here is my `server.js`:

```
server.get('*', (request, response) => {
  bundleRenderer.renderToString({ url: request.url }, (error, htmlPromise) => {
    if (error) {
      // Log the error in the console
      console.error(error)
      // Tell the client something went wrong
      return response
        .status(500)
        .send(error)
    }
    response.send(layout.replace('<div id=app></div>', htmlPromise))
  })
})
```

`getInfo()` is the method to fetch server data.

Here is `getInfo()`:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    getInfo(api) {
        return axios
          .get(api || this.$route.params.path)
          .then((data) => {
            this.data = data
            this.$set(this, 'isLoading', false)
          })
    },
  },
}
```

My server entry is:

```
import { app, router, store } from './index'

export default context => {

  let componentPromises = router.getMatchedComponents().filter((component) => {
    return component.methods && component.methods.getInfo
  }).map((component) => {
    return component.methods.getInfo()
  })

  return Promise.all(componentPromises).then(() => {
    return app
  })
}
```

However, I soon realize that all the components from `router.getMatchedComponents()` does not have `$route` or `$set`. Therefore, the method `getInfo()` stops working.

The document from https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-instance.html is very short and does not provide much information:

> **router.getMatchedComponents()**
>
> Returns an Array of the components (definition/constructor, not
>   instances) matched by the current route. This is mostly used during
>   server-side rendering to perform data prefetching.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: And that is exactly where the concept of store kicks in. Vuex can store data fetched from async api to an object shared across all the components. Checkout https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have previously incurred into a similar problem and managed to successfully prefetch data by doing the following:

```
app.$router.onReady(() => {
   const matchedComponents = app.$router.getMatchedComponents()

   if (!matchedComponents.length) { /* ... */}

   Promise.all(matchedComponents.map((Component: any) => {
     if (Component.options.methods.asyncData) {
       return Component.options.methods.asyncData({
         store: app.$store,
         route: app.$router.currentRoute
       });
     }
   })).then(() => { /* your callback here ... */ });
}
```

According to vue ssr documentation (https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/data.html) the suggested way is to use a custom asyncData method in your component to perform data fetching rather than calling component methods directly:

```
export default {
   asyncData ({ store, route }) {
      // return the Promise from the action
      return store.dispatch('fetchItem', route.params.id)
   }
},
```